# Use JPA @StaticMetamodel classes WITHOUT a local persistence.xml? (Remote EJB)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm trying to use a JPA service remotely via EJB with EasyCriteria's detached criteria generator (very cool feature) which does not require an EntityManager to write a query.

```
EasyCriteria<MyTable> myCriteria = EasyCriteriaFactory.createEasyCTO();
myCriteria.leftJoin(MyTable_.otherTable.getName());
```

Essentially, I do not want the EJB client server aware of the database, other than the schema (so no persistence.xml or data-source.)  But I want to use the Metamodel to enforce schema name safety on these queries.  The schema (entities and metamodel) are imported via Maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-schema</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

This jar contains both JPA entities and @StaticMetamodel classes, for example

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(MyClass.class)
public abstract class MyClass_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<MyClass, String> descr;

}
```

However, although MyClass (the entity) and MyClass_ (the metamodel) are available at compile time, the metamodel MyClass_ throws a NPE at runtime.  My debugger says "Class not loaded", which obviously seems odd.  Is there something special about these classes that would cause them not to load?  Do I need some other dependency?

This happens even is a JUnit test, so it's not a container issue it seems.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have a similar problem using a "backend" project as a dependency, metamodels throw NPE at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MyClass_ class goes into your classpath and eventually in your jar.

When using Maven this is how you can do it:

1. Generate the meta-model:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>process</id>
               <goals>
                   <goal>process</goal>
               </goals>
               <phase>generate-sources</phase>
               <configuration>
                   <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/java/</outputDirectory>
                   <processors>
                       <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor
                       </processor>
                   </processors>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Now your meta-model is located in target/generated-sources/java/ so in order to add them to your src/main/java you need to:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
         <execution>
              <id>add-source</id>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>add-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <sources>
                       <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</source>
                  </sources>
              </configuration>
         </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

Comment: I haven't had any issues with generation of the files, I do use JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor.  The classes exist, and are in a jar in the same package as the entities.  The entities are available at run time, the meta model is not.

Comment: Could it be that at compile time they are linked to other metamodel classes than at runtime?

Comment: There are no other metamodel classes in our system.  The only ones are in the jar called my-schema.jar

Comment: So does the tests pass or do you get a NoClassDefFoundError? If it's just the debugger than maybe it's the IDE that doesn't load the classes properly.

Comment: I'll have to checked that it is still happening, but I first saw this behavior in JBoss, then confirmed it with a test case.